# Using AuthGuard For Angular 17 routes

Tags: angular, angular17

I am following the docs of angular from [Angular Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn#description)

Below is my Guest Guard Code. The logic is to check if the user is available or not,

if available, redirect to dashboard else proceed to login page.

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()

class PermissionsService {
  canActivate(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

}

export const guestGuard: CanActivateFn =  (route, state) => {
  return inject(PermissionsService).canActivate();
};
```

But this code throws error as

```
[ERROR] TS2304: Cannot find name 'inject'. [plugin angular-compiler]

src/app/guards/guest.guard.ts:15:13:
  15 │       return inject(PermissionsService).canActivate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `inject()` from `@angular/core`.