# Angular 17 - functional guard - ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, angular17

I am migrating old angular project to latest angular 17. I changed class based auth guard to functional auth guard. The problem I am having is that I get this error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _UserService!
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:5626:27)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6069:33)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6069:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:911:40)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:917:42)
at inject (core.mjs:1001:12)
at authGuard (auth.guard.ts:6:23)
at router.mjs:3323:134
at runInInjectionContext (core.mjs:6366:16)
at router.mjs:3323:89
```

Here is my authGuard code:

```
import {CanActivateFn, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {inject} from "@angular/core";
import {UserService} from "../users/user.service";

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const userService = inject(UserService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  if (!userService.is_authenticated()) {
    router.navigate(['login', state.url]);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Here is part of my UserService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private usersUrl = '/users/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }

    ...

    public is_authenticated(): boolean {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        // Check whether the token is expired and return
        // true or false
        return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
    }
}
```

As I understand the documentation I don't need to provide UserService anywhere. Using 'inject' should be enough. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `UserService` provided in root ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler if you mean using @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) decorator in front of UserService. I tried it, but I get circular dependency: ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for _UserService.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler before I wrote this question I was also checking one of your answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571786/using-authguard-for-angular-17-routes

In the example given in this question, PermissionService doesn't use providedIn: 'root'. I tried the exact same code in my project, but I got the same error for PermissionService.

Comment: Can you share your userService ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I added necessary part of UserService to my question. But I think it should not be the problem, because to test this I created PermissionService mentioned in previous comment and the problem error was the same, just for PermissionService.

Comment: It is very well explained in the docs:https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn, but also there are many SO posts

Comment: I found out that the solution to my problem is that I add this to the route where authGuard is used: providers: [UserService, JwtHelperService, { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS }]. I am wondering if there is a better solution? Because there are multiple routes that use authGuard and would than need these providers as well.

Comment: inject it in the contstructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was adding this to providers in app.config.ts:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    UserService, JwtHelperService, { provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS },
   ...
]
```